# How do you earn the Convulsions achievement?

Tags: clicker-heroes

35 clicks per second seems like it's physically impossible.  Using the Clickstorm ability the best I can do is 27 clicks per second.

Is there any way to get this without cheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. I did it by holding my mouse sideways, hammering the primary mouse button with 3 fingers (while using an energized clickstorm).

Being able to do it legit depends on the type of mouse (I was unable to do it on my work mouse which has much smaller buttons). Using a website like [this](http://cookie.riimu.net/speed/) is helpful in testing what strategies work well.

That said, for me it took considerable effort and I think the achievement is aptly named.

Answer (score 4):

This one isn't so tricky to get; but it does take a little ingenuity.

First; you want to use an `Engergized Clickstorm`.  That gets you up to 20 clicks per second.  (which may be enough if you can click 15 times per second; if not; keep reading)

Then; what I ended up doing was using `Windows Mouse Keys` (a quick google will show you how to enable/disable this; offer void if you're not on a PC).  You can then use a combination of the `5` and `+` keys to easily get you past the 35 click threshold.

Of course; an AutoClicker would do this for you (but I consider that cheating as well).  Some gaming mouses may also give you the ability to set something like this up as well; but I'll assume you have a vanilla mouse like I do.

Comment: So without having actual convulsions this sounds impossible to do with a mouse alone.  To me, seems like pretty lousy game design.

Comment: I think the design was specific that the way to do it is to Energize a Clickstorm and click a lot. I've done this manually with those skills activated. You can click 15/s; it's not a design flaw. What I do is position my left hand's index finger on the left mouse button with enough pressure to be just above the activation point, and then put my right hand's index and middle finger on the front two knuckles of the left index finger, I use my  fingers and wrist with no elbow movement to click quickly. I don't have the genes for lots of fast-twitch muscles. Nor do I use a training exercise mouse.

Answer (score 1):

With the Reload Upgrade and the Energize Upgrade you can improve the autoclick rate up to 60 clicks per second.

Like this => Energize, Clickstorm, Reload, Clickstorm

And use all the other Skills at the same time too ;)

Comment: Tested this and it does not work.